How can I cause a line-break in HTML without interrupting the control-F "findability" of the text?
Imagine I have the following HTML:
<span>one two</span> <span>three four</span>

If the user presses control-F (or command-F on macOS), they can search for "two three" and it will successfully find/match the text across the two spans.
How can I insert a line-break in between the spans (so that "three" starts on a new line), while still making sure that the user can find the text with control-F the same way as before?
If I insert a <br> tag, or change the style of the spans to display: block, for example, then it no longer works. I can only find/match text within a single span. (In some cases, Chrome does allow me to paste a newline character into the find dialog — even though I can't type it myself — or I can find "twothree", but I want to be able to find the text as if there's a space in between: exactly "two three")
I'm willing to change the structure of the HTML if necessary.

I was able to get the behavior I wanted by putting &nbsp; in between the spans and using this CSS:
span::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

I was able to confirm that this works in Firefox too.

I've found a solution using the <wbr> element and a little bit of JavaScript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr
Here is the code :


let element = document.getElementById("paragraph"); // Get the element
let width = element.offsetWidth; // Get the current width of the element
element.style.width = width - 1 + "px"; // Set the new width to be the original width minus 1px
#paragraph {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: fit-content
}
<p id="paragraph">
  one two<wbr /> three four
</p>




Sorry, I should've mentioned that I need several line breaks, I plan to use this for a long passage of text.

That's all good, this solution is really not optimal after reflection.

Works with display:inline-block though:


span {display:inline-block; width:100%}
<span>one two</span> <span>three four</span>




I still can't Ctrl+F two three with this solution. Using Chrome.

@PeterPointer, yes, does not work in Chrome. but works in FF =))

I wondered if other browsers might have different behavior, this is actually good to know!
